# How to download images for reduce network usage?

Tags: image, retrofit

I am making android app that must show a lot of images from my REST API. I want to download images, and the next time check for images' name. If the image exists show them from the phone otherwise download from server.

Now I'm using Retrofit for my network requests and Glide for show images. But I have not good idea for solve this issue.

If needed I can change the network library or image loading library.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: This question might be too broad for the liking of S.O.*

What you want to do is make what is known as a cache. The idea is that you have a unique identifier (often refered to as a **key**) for each object in the cache, such as an md5 sum of the image data, or original name + date of creation.

When you want to display an image, you first check if the image exists in the cache. If it exists simply return with the image from cache. if it does not exist, start the download and upon completion you insert the image into the cache.

Here is an [example implementation](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/) that does what you want. I cannot vouch for it's quality because I never tried it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know that my question is too broad. But I couldn't find a good way.
But now You showed me a good way. Thank. I'm going to do this. I came back and accept this question if this do what exactly I want.